# How to close ServerSocket connection when catching IOException?

Tags: java, sockets

Sorry for question, but I'm totally noob in Java. What is the best practice to execute `ServerSocket.close()` when caught `IOException` from `ServerSocket`? According to docs, `ServerSocket.close()` throws `IOException` and compiler asks us to catch it. What is the proper way to close connection on `IOException`?

```
try {
    server = new ServerSocket(this.getServerPort());
    while(true) {
        socket = server.accept();
        new Handler( socket );
    }
} catch (IOException e) {
    if (server != null && !server.isClosed()) {
        server.close(); //compiler do not allow me to do because I should catch IOExceoption from this method also...
    }
}
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That's ugly in Java. I hate it, but this is the way you should do it: Wrapping it into another try-catch:

```
try {
    server = new ServerSocket(this.getServerPort());
    while(true) {
        socket = server.accept();
        new Handler( socket );
    }
} catch (IOException e) {
    if (server != null && !server.isClosed()) {
        try {
            server.close();
        } catch (IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace(System.err);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This *really* sucks!. Thanks for answer, its very useful!

Comment: Note, the new try with resources in Java 7.

Comment: Thanks, I've [seen](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) it. Looks awful.

Answer (score 8):

If you are going to close the ServerSocket outside of the try{}catch{} anyways, you may as well put it in a finally{}

```
try {
    server = new ServerSocket(this.getServerPort());
    while(true) {
        socket = server.accept();
        new Handler( socket );
    }
} catch (IOException e) {
    // Do whatever you need to do here, like maybe deal with "socket"?
}
finally {
    try {  
        server.close();
    } catch(Exception e) {
        // If you really want to know why you can't close the ServerSocket, like whether it's null or not
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

In Java SE 7 or later you can use [try-with-resources statement](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html), `ServerSocket implements java.io.Closeable`, so you don't need to explicitly `#close()` the socket when used in this way.

```
try (ServerSocket server = new ServerSocket(this.getServerPort())) {
    while(true) {
        socket = server.accept();
        new Handler( socket );
    }
} catch (IOException e) {
    // It's already closed, just print the exception
    System.out.println(e);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can close the resources in the finally block,

http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/finally.html

```
 } finally {
      try {
        socket.close();
      } catch(IOException e) {
         e.printStackTrace(); 
      }
}
```

Comment: Yes, that's true. But it still won't compile because of it might throw an IOException.

Comment: It doesn't make a sense. Compiler will also ask to catch `IOException` from `ServerSocket.close()`.

Comment: true, you should still wrap it with a try catch.