# Kotlin Nested Use Function for Java try-with-resource

Tags: sockets, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, outputstream, try-with-resources

My goal is to auto-close `Socket` and `OutputStream` in try-catch block.

After searching and learning from Java [try-with-resouce](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33644530/3466808), I ended up using `use{}` in Kotlin. However, it seems like nested `use{}` cannot be avoided:

```
suspend fun print(): LoadingStatus {
    var status = LoadingStatus.LOADING

    withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
        try {
            val printerSocket = Socket("192.168.x.xxx", 9100)

            printerSocket.use { socket ->            <- first use{}
                socket.getOutputStream().use {       <- second use{}
                    it.write("xxx".toByteArray())

                    status = LoadingStatus.DONE
                }
            }
        } catch (e: IOException) {
            Log.e("print()", "Printing Failed: please check your network")
            status = LoadingStatus.ERROR
        }
    }

    return status
}
```

Just wondering if there's a better way than using nested `use{}` for my goal. Any suggestion would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this particular case of a `Socket` and its `OutputStream`, it is unnecessary to `use` on both the `Socket` and the `OutputStream`, because the contract of `Socket.getOutputStream()` states that:

> Closing the returned OutputStream will close the associated socket.

(https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/net/Socket.html#getOutputStream())

Therefore, it is sufficient to do:

```
printerSocket.getOutputStream().use {
  ...
}
```